# How to iterate over an array stored in an object using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a call to an API endpoint which returns a single object. I want to loop over an array named `video` stored in the object and return all the links stored in the array to the view.

**JSON object returned from the API**

[image]

**html code**

```
<div class="myVideo" ng-repeat="v in courses.video">
     <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{'v.video'}}" 
      frameborder="10" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**Function in controller for API call**

```
$scope.getCourse = function(id){
        coursesFac.getCourseById(id)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.courses = response.data;
                var items =response.data;
                console.log(items);
                //console.log($scope.courses.video);
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load course data: ' + error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
    };
```

**This error appears on the view where videos should be displaying**
[image]

Comment: It looks like your array in `courses.video` is a string, try converting it to an array first because I don't see any issues with your ng-repeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`courses.video` is a string - not an array. You need to parse the json

```
$scope.getCourse = function(id) {
    coursesFac.getCourseById(id)
        .then(function(response) {
            response.data.video = JSON.parse(response.data.video); //HERE
            $scope.courses = response.data;
            var items = response.data;
            console.log(items);
            //console.log($scope.courses.video);
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load course data: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
};
```

Comment: This also applies to `enroled` (no typo)

Comment: @Weedoze So I added the parsing of the array to json as you showed in your answer. But I still get a  http://localhost:8080/v.video 404 () error. What am I missing here. Thanks

Comment: @SeanMcGrath What are you trying with this url ? 404 mean not found... This has nothing to do with the code provided

Comment: I have edit the question to show the error message displayed in the view. What I want is for all the video links to be displayed in the view. When i ng-repeat over the array I want the video displayed.

Comment: @SeanMcGrath I answered the question. There was an error with JSON parsing. This error is solved. Now you are coming with a total other problem

Comment: @Weedose This was part of the original problem, I was getting this error. But I taught it was down to the way I was using ng-repeat over the array. I have added your solution to my controller, but the error still occurs. Thanks Sean